# What is the most performant way to build and execute a multiple where clause in SQL from a single table of identifiers?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here's the challenge. Users want to be able to create filters based on N-criteria and the criteria being used for the filter is a fluid heirarchy. To simplify it, let's use two hierarchies that the user could select from:

1. All Territories

   - Europe

     - UK
     - France
   - Americas

     - US
     - Canada
     - Mexico
2. Media

   - Music

     - Downloads
     - CDs
   - Movies

     - Streaming
     - DVD

Objects would have a table of tags associated with them. The ObjectsTags table would contain an indicator as two which type of data the tag is linked to

The issue is that user would want to select and group the tags they want to filter by. So they might want Movies  in Europe so they would select those three tags as a single grouped filter. It's easy enough to get a filter based on those three tags that says:
Any object that has a tag of: (All Territories OR Europe OR UK or FRANCE) AND (All Media OR Movies OR DVD OR Streaming). The challenge is that I need to support any number of new hierarchies that might be needed and any level of filters, since a user could also want a filter that returns everything from that filter as well as all of the CDs in the US.

Is there any new feature in SQL Server that would be better suited for handling this type of a where clause in a performant way?

Answer (score 0):

You are either going to have to create your where clause dynamically, or you will pre-create the SQL using a where clause similar to the following:

```
where country = coalesce(p_country, country)
  and media   = coalesce(p_media, medias)
  and music   = coalesce(p_music, music)
```

> The really cool part of this statement? Your performance will be the
>   worst that it can possibly be.

I recommend creating a dynamic statement with the specific conditions you need.

Comment: I was actually thinking, worst case, I would populate temp tables using left joins and nulls to determine memberhip but I was hoping there was a new feature that would make this better than that. Plus, dynamic statements are limited in how long they can be and this could, potentially, be quite large.

Comment: @Josef You can stuff up to 2GB in varchar. So a SQL that wouldn't fit in that would be a real monster.  But the benefit of dynamic SQL is that you can be very specific about which criteria you add, depending on the input.  Which can benefit the performance of the SQL.